# Multi-tab dash app : Placing `dcc.Store` component in different tabs

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

Question on using `dcc.Store` in multi-tab structure app. I'd like to persist / store data switching between tabs. My multi-page / tabs dash app structure looks like:

- index.py
- app.py

  - Tabs

    - tab1.py

      - subtab1.py
      - subtab2.py
    - tab2.py

`index.py` renders the layout of from each file depending on the selection.

```
app.layout = html.Div([

    # tabs
    html.Div([

        dcc.Tabs(

            id="tabs",
            vertical=True,
            className="mb-3",
            persistence=True,

            children=[


                 dcc.Tab(label="tab1", value="tab1",
                         children=[dcc.Tabs(id="subtabs", persistence=True, 
                            children=[dcc.Tab(label='subtab1', value='subtab1'),
                                      dcc.Tab(label='subtab2', value='subtab2')
                            ],

                    )
                 ]),
                 dcc.Tab(label="tab2", value="tab2"),

            ],
            
        )

        ],

        className="row tabs_div"

    ),

        

        # Tab content
        html.Div(id="tab_content"),

])
```

Now, I'd like to exchange component state / data between different subtabs. `subtab1.py` contains `dcc.Graph` and `data-table` and 'subtab2.py `contains a series of dcc.Graph` components.

Do I need to add `dcc.Store` component in both `subtab1.py` and `subtab2.py` to store individual components and read from them? I'd like to be able to read components state of `subtab1.py` in `subtab2.py` and other files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to host your `dcc.Store` components within your `index.py` file, not within one of your tabs.

This is because when you switch tabs, everything housed in your `html.Div(id="tab_content")` will go away and become the new tab.  If you add a `dcc.Store` component within `subtab1.py` and `subtab2.py` or even within your `tab1.py` or `tab2.py` then those stored components will be gone and reset when you navigate to a different tab and lost when you go back to the first tab.  This is assuming you are using *"Method 1. Content as Callback"* described here (https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/tabs).

Additionally, when you click to a new tab, if you want the data to persist from what you put in your `dcc.Store` that is in your `index.py` you'll need to reload it on the new tab.  Look at the *"Updates on Page Load"* section here (https://dash.plotly.com/live-updates) for about how to structure your layout as a function.  That way you can provide the contents of your `dcc.Store` to it when reloading the tab so you can maintain the data collected from when the user was first on the tab.

I might also recommend using a different `dcc.Store` per tab, all stored within `index.py`.  That may simplify what you have to pass around to your different tabs.  For example, if you collect some data on `tab 1` that is independent from the data you collect from `tab 2`, then you won't need to pass your `dcc.Store` from `tab 1` into `tab 2` in order to cache your `tab 2` data.  However, your `tab 3` might need data from both `tab 1` and `tab 2`, so you can have 2 inputs to the layout of `tab 3` that correspond to the `dcc.Store` components that correspond to `tab 1` and `tab 2`.  However, an alternative might be to have one `dcc.Store` that is a dictionary with keys of `tab 1` and `tab 2` corresponding to the data you want to store from each tab.  I'm not totally sure if one method would be much better than another from a performance perspective, but I personally prefer a different `dcc.Store` per each "user input collection" tab that I can subsequently use on my "compile/output/visualization" tabs for organization sake.  It also allows you to persist information from different tabs differently (per session or memory for example) if that makes sense for your app.

Comment: do you have any small working example of how dcc.Store helps storing input data even when we switch tabs?