# could we save plot and data under tab when switching tabs?

Tags: plotly-dash

I have few tabs, and each tab contains heatmap with large dataset. so I use callback to generate heatmap for each tab. It does take a long time since data is large. after generating heatmap for each tab, when switching  tab, why I still have to wait for a long time to see the heatmap under the tab to show up?

Any option I can keep the plot and data inside tab, so when switching tabs, the plot will pop up immediately?

Thank you

here is the layout of tabs,

```
    graph_tabs = dcc.Tabs(
        [timeplot_tab,padcontour_tab,conformancecontour_tab],
        mobile_breakpoint=1000,
        className="tabs-container",
        id="graph-tabs",
        value="Well Time Plot",  # default value
    )

    grid_container = html.Div(
        [table_tabs,graph_tabs], id="grid-container"
    )
    # A container to place the grid below the top info
    container = html.Div([top_info, grid_container], id="container")

    app.layout = html.Div([navbar, container])
```

for each tab, I have:

```
    padcontour_loading=dcc.Loading( 
                                    id='loading-pad-contour',
                                    type='default',
                                    children=padcontour_graph      
                                    )
    padcontour_tab= dcc.Tab(
            [padcontour_loading],  
            label=label,
            value=value,
            id=f"{value}-tab",
            className="single-tab",
            selected_className="single-tab--selected",
            #style={'display':'inline-block'}
        )
```

then, in callback, I update heatmap for each tab

```
@app.callback(
    [
     Output("padcontour-graph", "figure"),
     Output("padcontour-markdown", "children"),
    ] ,
```

Comment: Have you looked into [Memoization](https://dash.plotly.com/performance) or [dcc Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63915648/multi-tab-dash-app-placing-dcc-store-component-in-different-tabs)?

Comment: Thank you Tobi, yes I used dcc.Store() which is extremly slow for me and I gave up for dcc.store(). I will check Memorization. Thanks for bring it up to me.

Comment: Please post the answer if it solves the issue, I'm really interested.

Comment: Hi Tobi, I followed the example of Flask-Caching with Redis, the result is the same. I don't see any improvement, when switching tab, it is still slow. any other solution?

Comment: I also tried cash dataset the other example and it is the same. no improvement. however I did get the warning of Exception possibly due to cache backend. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: